# Logging using Spring AOP

Tags: java, log4j, spring-aop

I would like to see line numbers of implementation class in my log and This is a snippet from my logging interceptor.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.application.package..*(..))")
    protected void initLogger() {
        //initilizing logger
    }

    @Before("initLogger()")
    @Order(1)
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        log.info(joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " is called "); // I dont need this statement's line # in log.
    }
    ...
}
```

This log.info produces below line in log:

```
2014-08-25 09:38:32,884 INFO http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-5 [com.application.controller.EmpController:11] - EmpInformation.getModel is called
```

The line number (#11) in log is NOT actual line number of EmpController but interceptors line number. I know a proxy is called behind the screen. But I would really prefer to have the actual implementation's line number (as it really helps to debug while production support), if there is any way.
Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

PS: I have a different log levels for packages. So I am afraid I would lose them, so I would not prefer to get logger instance for LoggingInterceptor class.

Comment: You want the line of the method being called and advised?

Comment: Yes. Lets say, EmpController calls EmpInformation.getModel and I would like to print at which line #, it is called "in" EmpController.

Comment: You can try having your interceptor implement Ordered. This affects the order in which proxies are applied. I have put this in a comment rather than an answer because I'm not 100% sure it will work. 


Edit: Actually you have @Order set already, so this is probably not good advice.

Edit #2: I don't believe 1 is the lowest order, so you might want to try Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE

Comment: Changing the order does not seem to help :(

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry I misunderstood your question. You are correct. I just need the line of method being called.  I think line of calling method is too much to ask :)